# Output using Messagebox in c#

Tags: c#

If I do not want to use "Messagebox.Show", what other option do I have in C#.

Comment: Where do you want to output to?

Comment: Is this for debugging? If it is, take a look at [`System.Diagnostics.Debug`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: you can use your own form, and  use  YourForm.ShowDialog(); for dialog displaying.

Comment: Maybe you could explain why you can't use the default MessageBox so we can better answer you.

Answer (score 4):

You can always create your own form and display it yourself, just like with any other form. If you could post some information about *why* you don't want to use `MessageBox.Show`, someone might be able to offer more specific advice.

Comment: There's really no specific reason, I was just wondering about that and couldn't find much about it online. From your answer I'm guessing that's pretty much the standard.

Comment: @brian, If you're talking about showing stuff to end users, that's far from true. In fact the de-facto standard is to get in the way of users as little as possible (which `MessageBox`es do big time) and use status bars, popup panels etc to display information. Message boxes are reserved for grave errors only.

Comment: @Blindy: My assumption was that the OP wanted the basic functionality of a message box without using `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox`. If the question is about how to display information to users (and it's truly that broad and unqualified), then that question is much too broad to answer here.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to display feedback messages to users.

If I'm not using a MessageBox, then I use a Label.

I set the text to "" or hide it and then when I want to display a message set the text and visibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about diagnostic output, that's what `Debug.WriteLine` (and its cousin, `Trace.WriteLine`) have been made for.

Comment: But wouldn't that be a console output. Trace.WriteLine wouldn't bring a message window, would it?